# Sending commands to a MSR606 Magstripe Reader/Writer with Winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I am trying to use an MSR606 Magstripe Reader/Writer with an Application I am coding in .NET Winforms.

After a significant amount of research and a few days of trial and error this is where I'm at.

*The reader is working through a COM port, I am able to create a reference to it in the application.

*According to the Manual it expects ANSI encoding

*Commands are listed with a Command Code such as "`<ESC><82>`" and a hex code such as "`1B 82`"

This is the code so far

```
CardReader = new SerialPort("COM4");
        CardReader.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataRecivedHandler);
        CardReader.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
        CardReader.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        CardReader.RtsEnable = true;
        CardReader.Open();
```

I haven't managed to successfully send a command to the reader. I've primarily tested by entering "CardReader.Write()" with commands as strings or byte arrays.

I have never worked with anything through a COM Port before so I've basically been blindly stumbling through this by looking up any guides I can. Any info on how to send commands of that format properly or just explaining where I've gone wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `DataRecivedHandler` getting called?

Comment: Completely forgot to mention that.  I've never gotten it to call the DataReceivedHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out that I was formatting the commands wrong. Sending them as hex codes was simply appending "0x" to the code and sending it as a byte[]

`CardReader.Write(new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x82 }, 0, 2);`